# How to animate just one Activity when Activity change?

Tags: android, android-activity, translate-animation

When  change from `Ativity A` to `Activity B` and viceversa  I want that **only** `Activity B` to animate, but in my case `Activity A` also animates.(leaving a blank space in the left of the screen) `Activity B` animation is working well, my problem is with the animation of `Activity A`.(which shouldn't exists). I have set

```
//Activity B
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fadein, R.anim.fadeout);
    setContentView(R.layout.mylayout); 
      //..........
  }
```

only in `Activity B`. I want that `Activity A` never animates or disappears from the screen.

I **fixed the reverse animation**(change from `Activity B` to `Activity A`) in this way:

```
//Activity B
@Override
public void onPause(){
    super.onPause();
    overridePendingTransition(0, R.anim.fadeout);
}
```

This works good, so, now the problem is only with the change from `Activity A` to `Activity B`, I would like the same behave of `Activity A`(just stay, no animation).
But If I try `overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fadein, 0);` in `onCreate()`, `Activity A` disappears from the screen.

fadein.xml

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator">
    <translate android:fromXDelta="100%p" android:toXDelta="0%p" android:duration="1000"/>
```

fadeout.xml

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator">
        <translate android:fromXDelta="0%p" android:toXDelta="100%p" android:duration="1000"/>
</set>
```

In the first image is what I get now, in the second image is what I want to get.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this.

**staystill.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromYDelta="0%p" android:toYDelta="0%p"
    android:duration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime"
 />
```

Comment: where should I place this animation?

Comment: I mean, how to use it, where to call it? Should I replace any of my animation with this one? Should I set it to `Activity A`? Please tell me.

Comment: `overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fadein,R.anim.staystill);` and then set `android:duration="1000"` in `staystill.xml` solves the problem.

Comment: I like your solution. But still I am getting black screen while animating new activitiy. Please provide solution to remove black screen.