# Activity Transition sliding in/out animation

Tags: android, animation, android-activity, android-xml

I know that are some example over the internet and also here on **Stackoverflow** I found many examples but belive it or not, none of them supply me needs. [Even I have asked a similar question few time ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14871637/how-to-animate-just-one-activity-when-activity-change) and I have stuck again into this problem. Basically is the same question but in the opposite direction. I can do whatever animation I want with `Activity B` but the problem here is `Activity A` which I could animate just in few scenarios.  Basically `ActivityA` play `enter_left` only in this combination:

`overridePendingTransition(R.anim.enter_from_right, R.anim.exit_on_left);`

What I want to do is to animate(move) just the `Activity A` either on `startActivity()` and `onBackPressed()` while `Activity B` stay unmoved on the screen. `Activity A` swould allways be drawn on top(as a sliding menu, I could do this with `Activity B`).
I really thought that the above snippet will do the work:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityA.this, ActivityB.class);
                startActivityForResult(intent, 500);
                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.stay_still, R.anim.exit_on_left);
```

but this does not even play any animation, while

```
//this is the animation for onBackPressed()
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.enter_from_left, 0);
    }
```

animates `Activity A` as I want but `Activity B` suddenly disappears from screen and I want to stay (setting `(R.anim.enter_from_left, R.anim.stay_still)` does nothing).

I have prepared all 5 necessary animations:

enter_from_left

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shareInterpolator="false" >

<translate
    android:duration="500"
    android:fromXDelta="-100%"
    android:toXDelta="0%" />
</set>
```

exit_on_left

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shareInterpolator="false" >

<translate
    android:duration="500"
    android:fromXDelta="0%"
    android:toXDelta="-100%" />
</set>
```

enter_from_right

```
    <set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shareInterpolator="false" >

    <translate
        android:duration="500"
        android:fromXDelta="100%"
        android:toXDelta="0%" />
   </set>
```

exit_on_right

```
    <set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shareInterpolator="false" >

    <translate
        android:duration="500"
        android:fromXDelta="0%"
        android:toXDelta="100%" />
   </set>
```

stay_still

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shareInterpolator="false" >

    <translate
        android:duration="500"
        android:fromXDelta="0%"
        android:toXDelta="0%" />
</set>
```

I have tried a lot of combinations but non of them worked. Could you please tell me if is this animation possible and if can it be done in this way? 
I will post an image, to be more clear what I want to do:

So, first step: on `startActivity()`, `ActivityA` should leave the screen from the left side and while moving, the `Activity B` shoull allready "be there", "below it".

[image]

Then, `onBackPressed()` `Acyivity B` should "come back", entering from the left side of the screen and overlapping the `ActivityB` that stay unmoved.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you tried this combination, but should work.-

```
startActivityForResult(intent, 500);
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.enter_from_left, R.anim.stay_still);
```

Comment: This makes `Activity B` enter from left while `Activity A` stays. The first argument is the animation for entering(new created) activity.

Answer (score 0):

I could find that the next one works very nice with fragments `fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.stay_still,R.anim.exit_on_left);`
while `overridePendingTransition(R.anim.stay_still, R.anim.exit_on_left);` does not work with activity.

On the other hand the reverse,

`overridePendingTransition(R.anim.enter_from_left, 0);` or
`fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.enter_from_left, 0);`

does not work with activity neither with fragments. The most close approach that works was
`transaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.stay_still,R.anim.exit_on_left, R.anim.enter_from_left,R.anim.exit_on_right);`

If anyone has any other solution, I'm still waiting to hear it and it will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

5 years later but there exists a solution for this.
These two functions needs be implemented in the activity which will override the default transition.

```
@Override
public void startActivity(Intent intent) {
    super.startActivity(intent);
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.from_right_in, R.anim.from_left_out);
}

@Override
public void startActivityForResult(Intent intent, int requestCode) {
    super.startActivityForResult(intent, requestCode);
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.from_right_in, R.anim.from_left_out);
}
```

from_right_in.xml

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate android:fromXDelta="100%p" android:toXDelta="0" android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/accelerate_decelerate" android:duration="300"/>
    <alpha android:fromAlpha="0.0" android:toAlpha="1.0" android:duration="300" />
</set>
```

from_left_out.xml

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate android:fromXDelta="0" android:toXDelta="-100%p" android:duration="300"/>
    <alpha android:fromAlpha="1.0" android:toAlpha="0.0" android:duration="300" />
</set>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

1. Add animations for activity transition in/out, in intent call like

   ```
   startActivity(new Intent(this,toActivity));
   overridePendingTransition( R.anim.slide_in, R.anim.slide_out);
   ```
2. Here is animations file, add this in anim folder

   **slide_in.xml**

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:fromYDelta="100%p" android:toYDelta="0%p"
       android:duration="300"/>
   ```

   **slide_out.xml**

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:duration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime"
       android:fromYDelta="0%p"
       android:toYDelta="100%p" />
   ```

**Thanks**

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if i really understand what you want, but if you want to create a sliding Menu, you could use this tutorial to implement it, it works just fine - It's an alternative to resolve your problem -:

http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html

But your have to use `FragmentActivity` instead of `Activity`. If you want an example, just ask for it and i will post it. Good luck.

Comment: No, I don't want this because a I have a flux of some activities that has to share this animation. This does not suppose to be a sliding menu.